# Is there a 'patsy' formula syntax for specifying "baseline" models for 'statsmodels'

Tags: python, linear-regression, statsmodels

I would like to use formulas to specify a "baseline" model for some models fitting using `statsmodels` For example, I'd like to be able to specify a formula to pass to a `olm` or `Logit` model that simply predicts the mean of the observed dependent variable for all observations. I know that I can get these numbers simply by calculating the mean of the observations for the dependent variable, but I would like to have a *model* that produces these results (e.g. so I can use its methods). Is there a `patsy` syntax for accomplishing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use a formula with only the intercept term, then you will get the mean/average of the dependent variable:

```
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf

data={'y': [1,5,9],                       # mean(y) == 5 
      'X': [[2013], [0.001], [19.99]]     # doesn't matter
      }
model = smf.ols('y ~ 1', data=data).fit()
model.predict(3.14)                       # ==> 5
```

Comment: I'm surprised that the result of `predict` is not the same dimension as its argument. That's not how I'd expect it to work.

Comment: I've got [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22580477/656912) related to the (odd) way in which `predict` returns results.